# Cannot read property items of null

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, mongodb, express

I am learning javascript and databases, so I am practicing by making a todo list application. Which add item dynamically in the lists. List is created through URL like http://localhost:3000/work creates a work list, but whenever I try to add something it shows an error.

my JS code:

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const app = express();

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(express.static("public"));

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/todolistDB", {useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true });

const itemsSchema = {
  name: String
};

const Item = mongoose.model ("Item", itemsSchema);

const item1 = new Item ({
  name: "item1"
});

const item2 = new Item ({
  name: "item2"
});

const item3 = new Item ({
  name: "item3"
});

const defaultItems = [item1, item2, item3];

const listSchema = {
  name: String,
  items: [itemsSchema]
};

const List = mongoose.model("List", listSchema);

app.get("/", function(req, res) {
  Item.find({}, function(err, foundItems){
    if(foundItems.length === 0){
      Item.insertMany(defaultItems, function(err){
        if(err){
          console.log(err);
        } else {
          console.log("Succesfully saved the items");
        }
      });
      res.redirect("/");
    } else {
      res.render("list", {listTitle: "Today", newListItems: foundItems});
    }
  });
});

app.get("/:customListName", function(req, res){
  const customListName = req.params.customListName;
  List.findOne({name: customListName}, function(err, foundList){
    if(!err){
      if(!foundList){
        //Create a new list
        const list = new List({
          name: customListName,
          items: defaultItems
        });
        list.save();
        res.redirect("/" + customListName);
      } else{
        //show the existing list
        res.render("list", {listTitle: foundList.name, newListItems: foundList.items})
      }
    }
  });
});

app.post("/", function(req, res){
  const itemName = req.body.newItem;
  const listName = req.body.list;
  const item = new Item ({
    name: itemName
  });

  if(listName === "Today"){
    item.save();
    res.redirect("/");
  } else {
    List.findOne({name: listName}, function(err, foundList){
      if(err){
        console.log(err);
      } else{
        foundList.items.push(item);
        foundList.save();
        res.redirect("/" + listName);
      }
    });
  }
});

app.post("/delete", function(req, res){
  const checkedItemId = req.body.checkbox;
  Item.findByIdAndRemove(checkedItemId, function(err){
    if(!err){
      console.log("Succesfully deleted the item!!");
      res.redirect("/");
    }
  });
});

app.get("/about", function(req, res){
  res.render("about");
});

app.listen(3000, function() {
  console.log("Server started on port 3000");
});
```

My ejs code:

```
<%- include("header") -%>

  <div class="box" id="heading">
    <h1> <%= listTitle %> </h1>
  </div>

  <div class="box">
    <% newListItems.forEach(function(item) { %>
      <form action="/delete" method="post">
        <div class="item">
          <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="<%=item._id%>" onchange="this.form.submit()">
          <p><%=item.name%></p>
        </div>
      </form>
    <% }); %>


      <form class="item" action="/" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="newItem" placeholder="New Item" autocomplete="off">
        <button type="submit" name="list" value="<%=listTitle%>">+</button>
      </form>
  </div>

<%- include("footer") -%>
```

Comment: what is the error message you are getting?

Comment: Take a look at this and see if it's similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62000735/typeerror-cannot-read-property-items-of-null-in-monogdb-using-nodejs

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: Cannot read property 'items' of null in monogdb using nodejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62000735/typeerror-cannot-read-property-items-of-null-in-monogdb-using-nodejs)

Comment: Can you explain exactly what you do to end up with this error ? (Which routes, with which data)

Answer (score 0):

The `List.findOne` function might return either one "List" `{ name: String, items: [itemsSchema]}` item or `null`. Unfortunately, you don't check for the `null` condition which can happen if this list hasn't been created yet in your database.

To solve this issue, you'll need to add an existence check for the `foundList` variable in your code.

If the `foundList` variable isn't null, then the foundList contains a list and a new item can be pushed to it.
Else if the `foundList` variable is null, you can create a new list with this name and the item you want to add to it.

```js
if (err) {
    console.log(err);
} else if (foundList !== null) {
    foundList.items.push(item);
    foundList.save();
    res.redirect("/" + listName);
} else {
    // List is not found, here you can create a new list with the item, or possibly return an error to the user (listName not found!)
    foundList = new List({ foundList: [item], name: listName });
    foundList.save();
    res.redirect("/" + listName);
}
```

PS: You could refactor the code I wrote above to reduce duplication.